# angular-cli install error "Native code compile failed"

Tags: angular-cli

I raised this as an issue in angular-cli GitHub but they asked me to instead raise it here as this is the more suitable place for such a report.

#### OS?

> Mac OSX (El Capitan v10.11.6)

#### Versions.

> `ng --version`:
>
> Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
>
> Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
>
> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16
>
> node: 6.5.0
>
> os: darwin x64

#### Repro steps.

> `sudo npm install -g angular-cli`

#### The log given by the failure.

> ...
>
> execSync@1.0.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/execSync
>
> node install.js
>
> [execsync v1.0.2] Attempting to compile native extensions.
>
> [execSync v1.0.2]
>
> Native code compile failed!!
>
> node-zopfli@2.0.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-zopfli
>
> ...

#### Mention any other details that might be useful.

I used to use `angular2-webpack-starter` and that also gave me this error on install. I was advised by someone to try `ng-cli` but get the same issue here with the error **Native code compile failed!!**. My app however still seems to function but no one seems to know why this error occurs or its implications.

Does anyone here know how to fix this error?